# FSharp.Data: EmbeddedResource option is ignored

Tags: f#, f#-data, fsharp.data.typeproviders

I am using the XML Type Provider with FSharp.Data. I have a line like this:

```ml
type internal SomethingFromXML = XmlProvider<"./Sample.xml", EmbeddedResource="MyLib, Sample.xml">
```

I set the `Sample.xml` to "Embedded Resource, Do Not Copy".

I packed the `MyLib` to a NuGet package and used it in another program. But when I now execute it, I get a `DirectoryNotFoundException` saying it can't find `C:\Path\To\My\SolutionWithMyLib\MyLib\Sample.xml`

So, it seems to ignore the `EmbeddedResource` directive. Is that not supported with the XML Provider, or am I missing anything?

Comment: Have you marked the Sample.xml as an embedded resource in the project?

Comment: I have, but the problem was elsewhere. The type was generated correctly, but I used `GetSample()` which doesn't use the embedded resource. I had to load the sample explicitly as a stream and use `Load()`.